# Standard Set Smilies/Smileys/Emoticons

Tags: emoticons

I am wondering if there are a set of standard emoticons which I can use with a set of opensource icons also. As a table e.g. `:) -> smile.gif` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page should help you: http://www.greensmilies.com/smilie-lexikon/
The descriptions are in German but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

The tango icons are free.

[image: Tango Emoticons]

[Yahoo Messenger](http://messenger.yahoo.com/features/emoticons)

[Windows Live Messenger](http://messenger.msn.com/Resource/Emoticons.aspx)

Comment: can you find a source for the icons that includes the mapping to text emoticons?

Answer (score 2):

Skype icons: http://factoryjoe.com/projects/emoticons/

This has good list of shortcodes. Free icons can be taken from here http://ebupof.deviantart.com/art/Pidgin-Old-Tango-Smilies-63215859 as Skype icons are not free.